# I deleted google play services and now want to force install a lower version?

Tags: android, adb

I used adb run (adb shell) for both deleting, and attempting to install the apk but it keeps sayng [ERROR:VERSION_DOWNGRADE] or something like that. Can I fix this without rooting the device or seeing samsung tech support. I have the apk to install it. But i want the specific version 12.6.85. I want to spoof in Pokemon Go. My android version is 9 pie. Samsung Galaxy s9.

Comment: How did you delete it? Using pm uninstall? Is it showing up under installed apps in settings?